# How do I write async/synchyronous variants of one Python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

It's normal to develop a simple implementation first. So, for example, we might start with a  non-concurrent program, and then add concurrency. I'd like to be able to switch smoothly back and forth.

For example, single-threaded (pseudocode):

```
   results=[]
   for url in urls:
      # This then calls other functions that call yet others
      # in a call hierarchy, down to a requests.request() call.
      get_result_and_store_in_database(url)
```

Async (pseudocode):

```
# The following calls other functions that call yet others
# in a call hierarchy, down to an asyncio ClientSession().get() call.
# It runs HTTP requests and store the results in a database.
# The multiple URLs are processed concurrently.
asyncio.run(get_results_in_parallel_and_store_in_db(urls))
```

With Python `async/await`, usually you wrap the run with `asyncio.run()` (compared to the loop you use in ordinary programs); then at the bottom of the  call hierarchy, you use an IO action like `aiohttp.ClientSession().get(url)` (compared to the ordinary `requests.request()`.)

*But*, in the async version, all functions in the call hierarchy between those two must be written as `async/await`. So, I need to write two copies of what is basically the same call-hierarchy, differing mostly in  whether they have the `async/await` keywords.

That is a lot of code duplication.

How can I make a switchably non-concurrent/async program?

Comment: Sync/async code has fundamentally different runtime expectations. It's a bit too broad to answer this hypothetically; a concrete example may be more answerable.

Comment: deceze: The answer by @sraw below shows  an example,  or  see my pseudocode above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really a big topic but not a general one. I personally have a private WebDAV project which implements both sync version and async version.

First, my WebDAV client accepts one argument named `client`, which could be a `requests.Session` or an `aiohttp.ClientSession` to perform sync requests or async requests.

Second, I have a base class to implement all common logic like:

```
def _perform_dav_request(self, method, auth_tuple=None, client=None, **kwargs):
    auth_tuple = self._get_auth_tuple(auth_tuple)
    client = self._get_client(client)
    data = kwargs.get("data")
    headers = None
    url = None

    path = kwargs.get("path")
    if path:
        root_url = urljoin(self._base_url, self._dav_url)
        url = root_url + path

    from_path = kwargs.get("from_path")
    to_path = kwargs.get("to_path")
    if from_path and to_path:
        root_url = urljoin(self._base_url, self._dav_url)
        url = root_url + from_path
        destination = root_url + quote(to_path)

        headers = {
            "Destination": destination
        }

    return client.request(method, url, data=data, headers=headers, auth=auth_tuple)
```

The fact is that both `requests.Session` and `aiohttp.ClientSession` support almost the same APIs, so here I could use an ambiguous call `client.request(...)`.

Third, I have to export different APIs:

```
# In async client
async def ls(self, path, auth_tuple=None, client=None):
    response = await self._perform_dav_request("PROPFIND", auth_tuple, client, path=path)

    if response.status == 207:
        return parse_ls(await response.read())
    raise WebDavHTTPError(response.status, await response.read())

# In sync client
def ls(self, path, auth_tuple=None, client=None):
    response = self._perform_dav_request("PROPFIND", auth_tuple, client, path=path)

    if response.status_code == 207:
        return parse_ls(response.content)
    raise WebDavHTTPError(response.status_code, response.content)
```

So finally my users can use it like `dav = DAV(...)` or `dav = AsyncDAV(...)`.

This is how I deal with two different versions. I think the idea is that you can pass those coroutines through the function calls, and only evaluate them at the highest level. So you only need to write different code at the last level but have the same logic at all other levels.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. But note that your two `ls` functions are near-duplicate code, and by DRY that should be avoided.

Comment: @JoshuaFox Agree, actually it is possible to avoid if I don't use `async/await` keywords but just use old `yield` style with `if` condition. But as we all know, the new style is much clearer and more beautiful. Further, I believe there is no way to completely avoid duplicated code, I am just trying to duplicate the least code by evaluating the coroutines at the most outside level.